# Function: next from HTML POST form, logging as undefined on submit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Having an issue with my form, trying to submit a website address/keyword and a selected filter. Filters are updated from database so that's why only one option is shown

```html
<div class="add-website-content">
            <span class="close-add">&times;</span>
            <h2>Add website or keyword</h2>
            <form method="post" action="/newWebsite" id="new-website-form">
                <label for="website-input">Website address or keyword</label>
                <input type="text" id="website-input" name="website" placeholder="Address or keyword">
    
                <label for="filter-select">Filter</label>
                <select id="filter-select" name="filter">
                    <option value='null'>Select a filter</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" id="submit-website-add">Save</button>
                <button type="button" id="close-website-add">Cancel</button>
            </form>
            
</div>
```

Here is the express js post function I've written

```js
app.post('/newWebsite', function (req, res, err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
    db.newWebsite(req.body.website, req.body.filter)
    res.redirect('/blocking.html')
})
```

Here's how the options are added to the select tag, although I've tried adding them manually and it doesn't make a difference sadly.

```js
// Load Filters onto webpage from DB
async function loadFilters() {
  const filterFetch = await fetchFilters();
  const ul = document.getElementById('filter-list');

  for (const i of filterFetch) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
    ul.appendChild(li);

    // Add to 'add website modal' select option
    const newOption = document.createElement('option');
    newOption.value = i;
    newOption.text = i;
    filterSelect.add(newOption, null);
  }
}

// Function to return list of filters
async function fetchFilters() {
  let filterFetch = await fetch('/filters');
  if (filterFetch.ok) {
    filterFetch = await filterFetch.json();
  } else {
    console.log('filterFetch failed');
    filterFetch = undefined;
  }

  return filterFetch;
}
```

which is linked to the following code in server and then queried. This is all working fine. It's just the method='post' from the form that is causing issues.

```js
app.get('/filters', asyncWrap(getFiltersJson));
```

The console.log(err) returns the following in the terminal:

```
[Function: next]
```

EDIT

Few more details, the form is accessible from inside my index.js file and logs in browser fine with the following

```js
const saveWebsite = document.getElementById('submit-website-add');
const cancelWebsite = document.getElementById('close-website-add');
const filterSelect = document.getElementById('filter-select');
const websiteInput = document.getElementById('website-input');

saveWebsite.onclick = () => {
  const websiteInputted = websiteInput.value;
  const filterSelected = filterSelect.value;

  // Add database push
  console.log(filterSelected);
  console.log(websiteInputted);
  console.log(filterSelect.selectedIndex);

  websiteModal[0].style.display = 'none'; // Close modal on save

  websiteInput.value = '';
  filterSelect.value = 'null';
};
```

Comment: For the route handler `app.post('/newWebsite', function (req, res, err) { //...` can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that the third parameter of any route handler would contain error information? [Express' guide on routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) (and the result of `console.log(err)` in this context) is pretty explicit about the third parameter of the callback being `next`, a function reference that, when invoked, passes the request to the next handler in the chain. As such, `if (err) {` will always return `true`.

Comment: @esqew Thanks for the reply. Yeah that makes sense. I removed the else so it just continues on and console now gives me the error
 [Function: next]
node:internal/process/promises:265
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: incomplete input] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}

Answer (score 0):

Issue was actually unrelated to the HTML and express post function, was a missing bracket db.run with INSERT:

```js
export async function newWebsite(website, filterName) {
  const db = await dbConnect;
  const index = db.all('SELECT filter_ID id FROM websiteFilters WHERE filter_name = ?', [filterName]);
  db.run('INSERT INTO blockedSites(site_address, filter_ID) VALUES (?, ?', [website, index]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So in this code you should try like this, according to their documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples)

```
app.post('/newWebsite', function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    db.newWebsite(req.body.website, req.body.filter)
    res.redirect('/blocking.html')
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

You must use `next` in parameters of callback, even though you don't make a use of it (or don't use anything and simply mention only `req` and `res`, but it's a good practice to put it everytime. And you can handle the error in that `try-catch` block